# send xlm from coinbase to stellar address using coinbase api

Tags: coinbase-api, stellar

i can send xlm from coinbase to my stellar address in their website. When i tried their sdk, i got error "XLM memo is required". First, my stellar address doesn't have a memo, Second, I can't find the xml field in the  sendmoney api document.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a fake memo. It will work both in the Coinbase website and with their API. The memo is an optional field used to identify a transaction being sent to exchanges, but when sending to a personal wallet, it is not required. However, Coinbase seems to mark it as required, and not providing it will result in transaction error. It's a Coinbase bug.

I just made a test my self, and I was able to send XML from Coinbase website to my Trezor wallet using `Coinbase` as memo. The XML appears on the wallet a few minutes after. Test it with a small amount first if you are not sure.

More info about memo being optional: [https://support.edge.app/support/solutions/articles/8000071636-what-is-a-stellar-xlm-memo-id-#:~:text=A%20Memo%20ID%20is%20generally,use%20when%20making%20a%20deposit](https://support.edge.app/support/solutions/articles/8000071636-what-is-a-stellar-xlm-memo-id-#:%7E:text=A%20Memo%20ID%20is%20generally,use%20when%20making%20a%20deposit).